# Grails: RESTful web services data processing in different format

Tags: web-services, rest, grails, exchangewebservices, groovyws

Currently I'm working on grails 2.4.3 with GGTS 3.6.0

**Requirement** - How a grails web service work.

**Existing** - Currently my closure is working for me as a web service but output is format specific(JSON or XML at a time).

**Problem** - In closure(web service), how I would be able to return JSON/XML and other format.

**Closure code** -

```
def able_Webservice = {

   ableService.populateAbleBean(ableBean);
   ableService.settingWhereClause(ableBean);
   ableService.getDBData(ableBean);
   def jsonData = ableService.webservice_Data(ableBean);
   render jsonData as JSON

}
```

Comment: have you tried [withFormat](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) closure?

Comment: How I can use withFormat? could you please provide simple example. How to call and how to process that URL into Closure?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails has [withFormat](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) feature. You can render different responses based on the incoming request Accept header, format parameter or URI extension.

Your code would like:

```
def able_Webservice = {
   ableService.populateAbleBean(ableBean);
   ableService.settingWhereClause(ableBean);
   ableService.getDBData(ableBean);
   def data = ableService.webservice_Data(ableBean);
   withFormat {
      xml { render data as XML }
      json { render data as JSON }
   }
}
```

This uses built-in [content negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the controller's [respond](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/respond.html) method to render your data in format most appropriate for the request. If the HTML response is chosen as the most appropriate, it will render a template determined by the `/views/controllerName/actionName` convention.

```
def able_Webservice = {

    ableService.populateAbleBean(ableBean);
    ableService.settingWhereClause(ableBean);
    ableService.getDBData(ableBean);
    def data = ableService.webservice_Data(ableBean);
    respond data
}
```